# Nginx Ingress - how to set redirect to external site if there is no matching route?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

beginner here. I am currently trying to configure Ingress to do two things - if the fibonacci route exists, redirect to the function and pass the parameter, if the route doesn't exist, redirect to another website and attach the input there.

So, for example, there are two basic scenarios.

1. https://xxx.amazonaws.com/fibonacci/10 -> calls fibonacci function with parameter 10 (that works)
2. https://xxx.amazonaws.com/users/jozef -> calls redirect function which redirects to https://api.github.com/users/jozef

I think the service doing the redirect is written correctly, it looks like this.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-redirect-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: api.github.com
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
      port: 80 # Default port for image
```

This is how my Ingress looks like. Experimented with default-backend annotation as well as various placement of the default backend, nothing worked. When I try to curl https://xxx.amazonaws.com/users/jozef, I keep getting 301 message but the location is unchanged. The final output looks like this

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2019 15:52:14 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://xxx.amazonaws.com/users/jozef

* Connection #0 to host xxx.amazonaws.com left intact
* Maximum (50) redirects followed
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

Does someone have an idea what am I doing wrong? This is my Ingress. Also, if it helps, we use Kubernetes version 1.14.6. Thanks a million

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /fibonacci/(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: fibonacci-k8s-service
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: api-gateway-redirect-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Did you use the -L option to accept redirects and -k to allow whatever server certificate such as in `curl -L -k https://xxx.amazonaws.com/users/jozef` ?

Comment: Hello, yes, I used both. Got somehow redirected to https://xxx.amazonaws.com/users/jozef, not to github

Comment: could you add the output of that with -vvvv option?

Comment: What if you curl http instead of https? It might be that you can 't do https because your ingress doesn't have a tls section where you provide a secret containing, a private key and a certificate to use.

Comment: Same result. What puzzles me is that in the logs, I dont see any attempt to redirect to github so I have no idea if the api-gateway-redirect-service was even hit or what is going on there

Comment: Hmmm I actually think, this is not supposed to work, because such a service only creates an entry in the kube-dns and doesn't get a cluster ip. it is mainly used to expose an external service to pods in the cluster.
I would let Our Senir brothers look into this one. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution to the problem was the addition of the `'Host: hostname'` header  in the curl command.

The service that was handling the request needed  `Host: hostname` header to properly reply to this request. After the `hostname` header was provided the respond was correct.

Links:

[Curl docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/)

[Ingress docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Answer (score 0):

So I ve kept reading about this subject and it turns out that ingress controllers generally don't go through services but connect to pods directly (it looks up pods selected by the service and configures them into nginx), wich makes the use case here (connecting to the serice that isn't backed up by anypod) destined to fail.

HOWEVER, it looks like that in recent version this has been supported by nginx ingress controller with nginx+ ONLY so far.

references:

[Support for Type ExternalName Services](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/externalname-services)

[Ingress uses Endpoints to configure PODs Ips in nginx config to load balance](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/)

Comment: Already found out what was wrong. I was "curling" the address of the network load balancer but my certificate was created for the address of the api gateway we use. And if the service wasnt found and ingress sent the request to the external site, the host didnt match. Therefore, I had to add parameter "-H 'Host: api.xxx.com'" to my command.